# How to check the SQL query result for specfic data while using Python+CGI+SQLite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, cgi

I need to check if table which holds credentials has record with matched username and password. I use `COUNT` because it's easier to parse one int value. How to check (using Python) if there are 1 or more records in credentials table?

```
    query = "SELECT COUNT(user_name) from credentials user_name='abc@abc.com' and pwd='123';"
    con = sqlite.connect(databasefile)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    while 1:
        row=cur.fetchone()
        if not row:
            break
        res=res+[row]
#check if there is 1 or more matched records ....
```

It's the result from server:

```
sqlite> SELECT COUNT(user_name) from credentials where  user_name='abc@abc.com' and pwd='1           23';
COUNT(user_name)
----------------
1
```

Answer (score 1):

From [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/):

> .rowcount
>
> This read-only attribute specifies the number of rows that the last .execute*() produced (for DQL statements like `SELECT`) or affected (for DML statements like `UPDATE` or `INSERT`).

```
if cur.rowcount > 0:
   ...
```

Comment: cur.rowcount is equal to -1 but I am sure the SQL is correct. Why?

Comment: I think as far as `.rowcount` is not working for SELECT I should use `len(row)` ...